# "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

Tags: ios, launching-application

My app was launching fine earlier today and now I'm getting this error

> **"Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"**

I've looked at other threads saying to change my code, but I never changed any code to get to this point.

Delegate.h

```
@interface halo4AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
    UIWindow *window;
    UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

Delegate.m

```
@implementation halo4AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize tabBarController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{   
    sleep(3);
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)dealloc {
    [tabBarController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The xib for my FirstViewController is titles FirstView.xib , ext

Comment: i saw a few problems in there.

Comment: first, you never set the window size ``self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];``, second you never instantiate the controllers that will be on your tabbar ``UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];`` and ``UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];``, third you don't initiate the tab bar with ``self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];``

Comment: and finally just add the controllers to your tabbar ``[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil]];``

Comment: after all that you add your previous code ``sleep(3);`` ``self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;`` ``[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`` ``return YES;``

Comment: Im pretty new to this, would you mind telling my where this code needs to go or perhaps place it in the code for me. BTW is there a way i can give u reputation or anything like that? thanks for all this help

Comment: just vote up if the answer helps and choose the answer if it helps, by the way if you need more help contact me by email on my profile, this is not a good place to make a discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error, more like a warning.

In your application delegate there is a method named `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in this method you have to make this line before the end of the method `self.window.rootViewController = [Some UIViewController]`

again, this is not an error, you can ignore the rootViewController IF you have another way to create this rootViewController.

**EDIT**

This is what your method should looks like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
  UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
  self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
  self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: My issue is that when i run the app in iOS simulator the launch screen is displayed followed by a black screen and nothing happens

Comment: can you post the ``application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`` ?

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: Im getting various errors, sorry for bothering you. Why are these changes necessary. Everything was working perfectly a few hours ago

Comment: can you give more details about your code? like post it on github or make a gist about the important classes. to help you i need more information, like the controller you want to start with, etc...

Comment: What is that "@" sign in `self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];`? Is it a new way to instantiate an array?

Comment: Sorry... Yes... This is how you can create an NSArray: `@[objects...]` if you want to use the old way: `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:objects, ..., nil]`